# Is there a way to enable/disable window resizing at runtime in qt c++

Tags: c++, qt

I have an application that has a settings window, and in that window I have a QCheckBox named "Resizable window", as you can probably tell it is responsible for enabling/disabling the ability to resize the mainwindow. I know you can write something like this in a constructor:

```
this->setFixedSize(x,y); //if the checkbox is checked
```

or

```
this->setMinimalSize(x,y); //if the checkbox is unchecked
```

but this does not satisfy me, I would like to enable/disable window resizing  at runtime. Is there a way to do that? Because clearly using this statements inside of functions does not work.

Comment: Re. `I would like to change this properties at runtime`: those calls to `setFixedSize` etc. *do* set those properties at runtime.  Please provide a [mcve] and state clearly the problems you are seeing.

Comment: @G.M. What I mean by that is: when I check the checkbox I want to be able to resize the window, but as soon as I uncheck it I want to have the window unresizable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling [`setFixedSize()`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/kernel/qwidget.cpp.html#_ZN7QWidget12setFixedSizeEii) is essentially calling both `setMaximumSize()` and `setMinimumSize()`. Therefore, to undo the effect, you can set the minimum size to 0, and maximum size to `QWIDGETSIZE_MAX` (2^24 - 1, or 16777215).

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QCheckBox>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto checkbox = new QCheckBox{tr("Resizable")};
    checkbox->setChecked(true);
    this->setCentralWidget(checkbox);

    this->resize(200, 100);
    connect(checkbox, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, [this](int state)
    {
        if (state != Qt::Checked)
            this->setFixedSize(this->width(), this->height());
        else
        {
            this->setMinimumSize(0, 0);
            this->setMaximumSize(QWIDGETSIZE_MAX, QWIDGETSIZE_MAX);
        }
    });
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}
```

Comment: It works :) But is there a way to change the "maximized" icon - when you can resize the window it shouldn't be dimmed, and it shouldn't be white when you can't resize it

Comment: `Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint` can help you with that. See the [`Window Flags Example`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html). `Qt::Window | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint` will disable the maximize button